# RewriteRule not working without R flag

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need this URL :
http://example.net/aroundtheshows/get?id=123

to be rewritten (not redirected) to :
http://example.net/ats/get?id=123

so I added the following RewriteRule in my htaccess :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^\/aroundtheshows
RewriteRule ^aroundtheshows(.*)?$ ats$1 [L]
```

But it does not work, I get a 404.

However if I had the R=301 flag, the redirection works properly (though that's not what I want, but it means the match is correct).

thanks !

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? facing the same issue :-\

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you are looking to visit

`http://example.net/ats/get?id=123` and have it masked as that URL while serving content from `http://example.net/aroundtheshows/get?id=123`?

In that case simply inverse your rule - no need for the `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteRule ^ats(.*) aroundtheshows$1 [L]
```

Demo here: http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=1392f5a6-c631-5e90-9ef5-6622644ed517

Comment: No, when I visit http://example.net/aroundtheshows/get?id=123 I want to serve content from http://example.net/ats/get?id=123. This gives me a 404. I also tried with http://htaccess.mwl.be/ who says everything is OK but it's actually not working when in the htaccess...

Comment: Dumb question then maybe but does your resource actually exist cause your rewrite rule is fine...

Comment: Yes it does exist, when I visit http://example.net/ats/get?id=123 I get the content.